# Calculate Moving Speed of USER in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gps

I need to calculate Speed with which the user is moving. So we need two things to calculate speed which are GPS and Accelerometer.

But both have their limitations.

1. GPS is not available all the time.While I getting the current
   location of user always I am getting from Network provider only and
   not from GPS.
2. Accelerometer is not accurate.

So which approach should I go with?

Comment: for speed using GPS or Network Provider

Answer (score 0):

Accelerometer is not reliable , for now you can try testing, and tweaking stuff to meet your requirements.

Check here:

https://github.com/bagilevi/android-pedometer

One of many features:

> calculate distance and speed based on user’s step length

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below way of getting the speed of moving using the GPS

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView textView;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;
    private double lat;
    private double lng;
    private static int UPDATE_INTERVAL = 1000;
    private static int FATEST_INTERVAL = 1000;
    private static int DISPLACEMENT = 0;
    private double speed = 0.0;
    double currentSpeed,kmphSpeed;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (!runtime_permissions()) {
            requestLocations();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        //stop location updates when Activity is no longer active
        if (mFusedLocationClient != null) {
            mFusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(mLocationCallback);
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private void requestLocations() {
        LocationRequest mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
//        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FATEST_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(DISPLACEMENT);

        mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback, Looper.myLooper());
    }

    LocationCallback mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
            List<Location> locationList = locationResult.getLocations();
            if (locationList.size() > 0) {
                //The last location in the list is the newest
                Location location = locationList.get(locationList.size() - 1);
                Location location2 = locationResult.getLastLocation();
                lat = location.getLatitude();
                lng = location.getLongitude();

                speed = location.getSpeed();
                currentSpeed = round(speed,3,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
                kmphSpeed = round((currentSpeed*3.6),3,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);

                //speed in km/h
//                speed = (int) ((location.getSpeed() * 3600) / 1000);
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        textView.setText("speed=== "+speed+"\ncurrentspeed==="+currentSpeed+"\nkmph speed === "+kmphSpeed);
                    }
                });
//                Log.i("SensorTestActivity","SPEEDDDDDspeed=== "+speed+"     ");
            }
        }
    };

    public static double round(double unrounded, int precision, int roundingMode) {
        BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(unrounded);
        BigDecimal rounded = bd.setScale(precision, roundingMode);
        return rounded.doubleValue();
    }

    private boolean runtime_permissions() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 100);

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == 100) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                onResume();
            } else {
                runtime_permissions();
            }
        }
    }
}
```